# Zero-Inflated Quasi-Poisson Models in R (glmmadmb, pscl)

Tags: r

Q:  Can a valid, zero-inflated Quasi-Poisson model be fitted in R?

I know zero-inflated Poisson and zero-inflated negative binomial both can be fitted with each `pscl::zeroinfl()` and `glmmADMB::glmmadmb()`.

However, in the help-file examples for `pscl::zeroinfl()`, the Quasi-poisson is fitted without inflation but omitted from the inflation demonstration:

```
## data
data("bioChemists", package = "pscl")

## without inflation
## ("art ~ ." is "art ~ fem + mar + kid5 + phd + ment")
fm_pois  <- glm(   art ~ ., data = bioChemists, family = poisson)
fm_qpois <- glm(   art ~ ., data = bioChemists, family = quasipoisson)
fm_nb    <- glm.nb(art ~ ., data = bioChemists)

## with simple inflation (no regressors for zero component)
fm_zip  <- zeroinfl(art ~ . | 1, data = bioChemists)
fm_zinb <- zeroinfl(art ~ . | 1, data = bioChemists, dist = "negbin")
```

and the only options for dist are `dist = c("poisson", "negbin", "geometric")`.

In the help-file documentation for `glmmADMB::glmmadmb()`, the negative binomial is `family="nbinom"` while the Quasi-Poisson is `family="nbinom1"` and the argument definition for `zeroInflation` states:

```
zeroInflation: whether a zero-inflated model should be fitted 
              (only "poisson" and "nbinom" families).
```

My understanding is that Quasi-Poisson models have the advantage of accounting for overdispersion (albeit in a linear fashion); that is if P is Poisson and Q is Quasi-Poisson:

[image]

but perhaps because [they lack a proper likelihood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-likelihood) they cannot be as easily implemented and that's why they are apparently omitted from two of the more popular zero-inflated packages...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Q:  Can  a valid, zero-inflated Quasi-Poisson model be fitted in R?

A:  YES, a valid, zero-inflated Quasi-Poisson model be fitted in R.

Set aside `pscl::zeroinfl()` and focus on `glmmADMB::glmmadmb()`.

A few things for `glmmADMB::glmmadmb()`:

- `family="nbinom1"` is still a negative binomial model with a valid likelihood -- the help-file just states that the parameterization corresponds to a quasipoisson.  If you dig through the guts of `glmmADMB::glmmadmb()` you'll see that "nbinom", "nbinom1", and "nbinom2" are all changed to `family="nbinom"` and that specifying "nbinom1" just creates a flag to submit `tau=alpha` instead of `tau=(1+e1+lambda/alpha)` in the [.tpl file](https://github.com/bbolker/R2admb/blob/master/R2admb/tests/inputs/glmmadmb.tpl).
- Furthermore, the package maintainer uses `family="nbinom1"` and `zeroInflation=TRUE` as the preferred model in an analysis about [owls displayed on page 17 of a PDF at the ADMB website](https://groups.nceas.ucsb.edu/non-linear-modeling/projects/owls/WRITEUP/owls.pdf):

  gfit3 <- glmmadmb(NCalls(FoodTreatment+ArrivalTime)*SexParent+
  offset(logBroodSize)+(1|Nest),
  data=Owls,
  zeroInflation=TRUE,
  family="nbinom1")
- While [this discussion](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mixed-models/2012q1/018054.html) is not about a `zeroInflation=TRUE` and `family="nbinom1"` model, Ben explains the parameterization of nbinom1 vs. quasi-poisson in the `zeroInflation=FALSE` case.

Comment: why was this asked and answered by the same person in the same 1 minute period? Seems like self-promotion to me

Comment: This Q&A format is [encouraged by SO](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).

Comment: For what it's worth I would say this is **not** a quasi-likelihood model, it's a MLE model that happens to have similar mean-variance relationships as the corresponding QL model.